# PHP artisan command returns nothing

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, bluehost

I just moved my Laravel application to production server. I am trying  to execute `artisan` command via PuTTy which ends with

> [Error Exception] Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

**What I've tried**

Reading about the topic, forum suggested few things

1) Setting file permission for storage directory to `0755`

2) Tried executing `artisan` command using `php-cli`. At bluehost I can access 
php-cli at `/ramdisk/php/54/bin/php54-cli`

**Command**

`/ramdisk/php/54/bin/php54-cli artisan list`

**Result**

Commands ends up showing nothing.

Any pointers towards issue are highly appreciated.

Comment: You should have a look at your logs (usually `storage/logs/`)

Comment: Thanks @rap-2-h for your time.  I checked the logs already at `larave.log` file is empty and there is nothing I can proceed with

Comment: have you ssh access on server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 5.2 [is not compatible](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation#server-requirements) with PHP 5.4, it seems you are using it.
You may consider to update your PHP version to PHP >= 5.5.9 (or, worst solution, downgrade Laravel). It can not work with this version.

Anyway, if you want to understand error, you could have a look at your logs (in `storage/logs/`), but maybe it's empty, due to the incompatibility mentioned above.

**EDIT**

`php-cli` version must also be >=5.5.9 if you are using laravel 5.2. Make sure you point out to the right php file

Comment: I've 5.6.24 currently running. and the application works fine. I think I will require a compatible `php-cli` version installed e.g something like `php56-cli` , What do you think ?

Comment: Yes. php-cli must be >= 5.5.9 too. Your php server version does not matter here.

Comment: I was able to successfully run the command by `/usr/php/56/bin/php artisan list`. Just referenced the right php file to execute and it worked . Thanks btw, for your time @rap-2-h